# HTML items not getting positioned on the right using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, alignment

I am trying to align my items list to the right side of the web page. Also, I wanted to have a vertical thin separator between the left and center data structure (hierarchy) and my right list.

Right.component.html :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="header-divider">
  <ul class="selection-list">
    <li *ngFor="let item of getSelections()">
      <button class="btn" (click)="deselect(item)" *ngIf="item.selected">
        <i class="fa fa-close"> {{ item.displayName }} </i>
      </button> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Right.component.css :

```
.selection-list {
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #555;
  padding-left: 23px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  right: 0;
}

.btn {
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  background: none;
}

.header-divider {
  border-left:1px solid #38546d; 
  height:30px;
  position:relative;
  right:20px;
  top:10px; 
}
```

Right now, it just appears below my hierarchy structure. What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always favor the use of [flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) which is a great simple way to use all available space inside a container. This is how I would do it:

-----(Edited)-----

```css
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    height: 50px;
    border: solid 1px peru;
}

.sendToRight {
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="PLCheck">
        fortuneSelect
    </div>
    <div class="sendToRight"> <!-- add class to div for manipulation -->
        rightSideComp
    </div>
</div>
```

In this example, the `margin-left:auto` makes your `.sendToRight` div move all the way to the right. You could also use `justify-content: space-between;` in your container element to achieve the same result.

Comment: @brunouno- This is actually moving the list items to the bottom-right of the page. The html code for the center and left parts are in different files. The posted html file is only for this right-side component. How can I implement using flex when the remaining content is in other files? Thanks!

Comment: Is there any place where I can see the full markup? At least the parent element and both children (the content you need to be side-by-side).

Comment: I have edited the question! The productline component calls the rightside component (which is the list on the right)

Comment: So we would like for `<div class="PLCheck"...>` to be on the left, and `<div><rightside-component...` on the right, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, correct! That is calling the fortune-select component which is loading the hierarchy. I want the <rightside-component> on the right of this hierarchy. I am just displaying the nodes which are selected (check-boxed) from the hierarchy.

Comment: I have updated the answer and added a snippet so you can see it working.

Comment: This works. The only issue is that when I add that css code, the hierarchy structure (on the left)  stops being scrollable. I am not able to view the hierarchy completely (i.e when I try to traverse the child nodes, after one point, I cannot scroll further down the page). When I remove this css code, it works as expected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177821/discussion-between-tee-jay-and-brunouno).